# SQL Server unpivot multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I'm trying to pivot a table around it's many columns to get to 3 columns (pivot, column name, value)

so for example:

```
name  |  age  |  gender
------+-------+---------
John  |   20  |    M
Jill  |   21  |    F
```

would become:

```
name | column | value
-----+--------+-------
John |  age   |   20
John | gender |   M
Jill |  age   |   21
Jill | gender |   F
```

I've googled quite a bit but haven't found a similar situation - especially since the pivot seems to be done in the opposite direction as what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 48):

The conversion of columns into rows is called an `UNPIVOT`.  You didn't specify what version of SQL Server you are using but there are several different ways to get the result.

You can use `SELECT` with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT name, 'age' as column, cast(age as varchar(10)) as value
FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT name, 'gender' as column, gender as value
FROM yourtable;
```

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, then you can use the UNPIVOT function:

```
SELECT name, column, age
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    name, 
    age = cast(age as varchar(10)), 
    gender
  FROM yourtable
) d
UNPIVOT
(
  value
  for column in (age, gender)
) unpiv;
```

Finally, instead of the UNPIVOT function you could also use `CROSS APPLY` with either `VALUES` (2008+) or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT name, column, age
FROM yourtable
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
    ('age', cast(age as varchar(10)),
    ('gender', gender)
) c (column, value);
```

Any of these versions will give you the result that you want.  You'll note that I had to cast the `age` column to a `varchar`. This is because the datatype/length (in unpivot) of the columns must be the same since you will be transforming them into a single column in the final result.

Comment: Might want to point out, in my testing on a SQL 2008 server, that the max_length also needed to match, so if Gender was char(1), it also needed to be cast for the unpivot to happen. Haven't tried with the outer apply, though.

Comment: so what you're saying is, in my search for how to use pivot, since i found only the opposite applications, i should have looked at UNpivot... brilliant!! : )  thanks!

Comment: @JaazCole It is only UNPIVOT that requires the datatype to be the same length - see this on [DBA.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54353/why-does-sql-server-require-the-datatype-length-to-be-the-same-when-using-unpivo)

Comment: that `CROSS APPLY` trick is awesome. it actually seems to be more flexible and IMO more readable than using `UNPIVOT`

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` is a great solution but I suspect you may need to quote `[column]`

Comment: Upvote for the use of `CROSS APPLY` with the table valued constructor. I've never seen this mentioned before and it was just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, column, value
FROM (SELECT name, age, gender
FROM table) src
UNPIVOT (value FOR column IN (age, gender)) pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it  easily with the 'WITH'-Clause and a generated helper-column. In
the first cte you generate temporary column, in the second, you unpivot it and in the the third you put it together again. Voila!

Comment: its 2024, I'm on SQL 2019, anybody can help why this code produce error ? Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 ---> ` ('gender', [gender])`     Incorrect syntax near ','.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY adl_id, ma_id) AS rk, 
adl_id, 
ma_id, 
ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR,fosa_id),'') fosa_id,
ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR,kdah_id),'') kdah_id,
ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR,lb_id),'') lb_id,
ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR,sprach_id),'') sprach_id
FROM tm_lieferant WHERE adl_id=1004)
,cte2 AS (SELECT rk, fieldname, [value] FROM (
SELECT rk, fosa_id, kdah_id, lb_id, sprach_id FROM cte1 ) p
UNPIVOT([value] FOR fieldname IN (fosa_id, kdah_id, lb_id, sprach_id
)) AS unpvt)
,cte3 AS (SELECT cte1.adl_id, cte1.ma_id, cte2.fieldname, cte2.value FROM cte2 INNER JOIN cte1 ON cte2.rk=cte1.rk)
SELECT * FROM cte3
```

Comment: This question already has an answer with over 42 upvotes. Why do you prefer you approach over theirs? Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you think it's the best approach?