# Convert specific columns to rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am selecting PatientID, Location, LN, FN, ServiceCode1, ServiceDate1, ServiceCode2, ServiceDate2 from a table. I am trying to list each service and corresponding date as its own row. The attached image shows how I want this to look highlighted in green. I've tried using the PIVOT function but with no luck. 
[image: ColumnToRow]

Comment: You actually want `UNPIVOT`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828346/sql-server-unpivot-multiple-columns

Comment: Second the UNPIVOT. Could you provide sample data? thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a Cross Join

```
Select  A.PatientID
       ,A.Location
       ,A.Last_Name
       ,A.First_Name
       ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Join (
              Values ('Service_Code1',A.Service_Date1)
                    ,('Service_Code2',A.Service_Date2)
            ) B  (Service_Code,Service_Date)
```