Transpose columns to rows - multiple columns
I have a query output that is formatted like this:



yr_mo
Sales
Transactions
Items
Shipping Cost
Tax




2024-04
20
50
100
12
2


2024-03
10
25
50
6
1



This isn't a great way to view the data, since the data is more columns that what I put in above.
What I'd like to do is to transpose the data via SQL so that the data looks like this:




2024-04
2024-03




Sales
20
10


Transactions
50
25


Items
100
50


Shipping Cost
12
6


Tax
2
1



With this format, the larger number of metrics will be much more readable in the format in which this information will be presented.
I've tried following a few guides for using the UNPIVOT and UNION ALL functions but haven't had success, since the guides I've looked at are only moving one singular column to a row, not a larger amount.
Query for reference - initial output:
select
YR_MO,
sum(order_volume) as Sales,
sum(transaction_count) as Transactions,
sum(items_shipped) as Items,
sum(freight_charge) as ShippingCost,
sum(tax_incurred) as Tax
from consolidated_data
group by 1


You listed your first query output but not what the data actually look like.  Should we assume the table looks like your first query output?  Also tag your DBMS.

The table is relatively simple - just a row per tranasction, and then the query will sum values based on the yr_mo of that transaction. And the DBMS is Snowflake

A SQL query is static. In your case there would be two result columns named "2024-04" and "2024-03". Is this what you want, regardless of the data in your table? If you rather want the columns dynamically matching what is in your table, then you'd have to do the layout in your app instead of doing this in SQL.

For now, the static 2024-04 and 2024-03 column names will work. I can then try an iterate a better solution once I have this spun up. Thanks! @ThorstenKettner

Another problem with doing this in SQL is that the columns would have to contain whatever data. So, if it is a price, will the user want to see a comma or a dot as decimal separator? If it is a date, will they want 'dd/mm/yyyy' or 'mm/dd/yyyy' or some other format still? The columns will have to be strings containing the values in the desired formats, but such information is stored in the settings of the users' UIs, and the DBMS is oblivious of what formats the users want. I'd do this layout thing in the app (loop in a programming language to fill the grid).

Don't do such things in SQL, use your application.

have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828346/sql-server-unpivot-multiple-columns

Try this. First convert columns "sales,transactions,items,cost,tax" into row. After that convert rows "2024-04,2024-03" into columns.
Query:
select 
type,
max(case when yr_mo='2024-04' then val end) as `2024-04`,
max(case when yr_mo='2024-03' then val end) as `2024-03` 
from (
select case when rn=1 then 'Tax' when rn=2 then 'Shipping_Cost' when rn=3 then 'Items' when rn=4 then 'Transactions' when rn=5 then 'Sales' else '' end as type,
yr_mo, val
from (
select 
yr_mo, 
row_number() over(partition by yr_mo) as rn,
val 
from sales_table 
lateral view explode(array(sales,transactions,items,cost,tax)) org as val) calcultd ) calcultd2 
group by type;
 

